# Show $1-1/x <\ln(x) <x-1$ for all $x>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Show $1-1/x <\ln(x) <x-1$  for all $x>1$?

My attempt:

(1) $\ln (x)<x-1$

Suppose $h: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto t-1-\ln(t)$, then $h'(t)=0$ if $t=1$. Furthermore $h'(t)>0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

(2) $1-1/x<\ln(x)$

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto \ln(t)-1+\frac{1}{t}$, then $f'(t)=0$ for $t=1$ and $f'(t)>0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Therefore the inequality is true.

Comment: What is the question? – See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324345/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161278/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/551858/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222872/42969

Comment: Is it possible to prove it like i did?

Comment: It surely is. Did you compute the derivatives? Can you show that they are positive? If not, what is the problem? – You'll find many similar solutions in the above-mentioned Q&As.

Comment: The sample solution uses the mean value theorem...

Comment: This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1161290/42969 uses the derivative, and this as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1419099/42969.

Answer (score 3):

$\forall t> 1, \,\, \dfrac1{t^2}<\dfrac1t<1$ thus for $x>1$ we have : $$\,\,\int_1^x\dfrac{dt}{t^2}<\int_1^x\dfrac{dt}{t}<\int_1^xdt$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=x-1-\ln(x)$$ then $$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-1}{x}>0$$ for $x>1$ and $$f(1)=0$$ so $f(x)$ is strictly monotonously increasing .