# Finding multivariable limits for the function $\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Could anyone help me with this

Find $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ if this limit exists

I tried using the squeeze theorem, but I could not find a suitable expression for the squeeze theorem as I could not find any number that allow me to squeeze the limit in between and cancel the denominator

Comment: did you try $2|xy|\le x^2+y^2$ and also $|x|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @angryavian, that doesn't seem to be the same as the original question. Is the $x^2+y^2$ intended to be in the denominator?

Comment: Yup it is intended to be the denominator

Comment: Does L hopital rule work for limits like this?

Comment: No, there is no L'Hôpitals Rule for multivariable limits.

Comment: See related techniques [(I)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889480/multivariable-limit-with-logarithm/890501#890501), [(II)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262874/show-that-g-is-continuous-at-0-0).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta) for a general case.

Answer (score 8):

Polar coordinates:
$$\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2}=r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta$$
and as $r=\|(x,y)\|$...

Answer (score 5):

$x^2\leq x^2+y^2$, then $0\leq\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$, now we obtain
$\left|\dfrac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq 3|y|$, since  $|y|\to 0$ we get  $\dfrac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\to 0$.