# How to prove a limit exists using delta and epsilon?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am having issues writing a proof using deltas and epsilons for this limit:
I basically do not  how to construct a proof after finding a limit. My main problem with problems like that arise from the proof. I took the the path of y=x and y =-x
to come up with L= 0.
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Thanks,
Mo.

Comment: I would try going into polar coordinates, writing $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Related techniques: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889480/multivariable-limit-with-logarithm). Here is a how.

$$ \Bigg| \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0 \Bigg| = \frac{|x|\,|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \epsilon = \delta. $$

**Note:**

> $$ |x| = \sqrt{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}. $$

Comment: Short and sweet! Good work!

Comment: @user175623: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think the limit is?  If I give you an $\epsilon$ that is positive, you need to find a $\delta$ so that over the whole square $-\delta \lt x,y \lt \delta$ the expression is within $\epsilon$ of the limit.  It seems that $x=\pm y$ will yield the extreme values.  What are your issues?

Comment: The limit = 0, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: user164587's comment is quite useful.  You will get a function of $r$ times some trig functions in $\theta$.  The trig functions are easy to bound.