# Compute the following integral: $\int_D \ln(x^2+y^2)dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Compute the following integral: $\int_D \ln(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ where $D$ is the disc $x^2+y^2 \le1$ in $R$ into polar coordinates.

What I have tried:
$r^2\le1 \implies r\le1$ we also have $0 \le\theta\le2\pi$

This produces $$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\int_0^1\ln(r)\cdot r dr \implies 2\pi\int \ln(r)\cdot r dr$$

Taking the integral by parts to tackle the $dr$ integral we have $du = \frac{1}{r}$ and $v = \frac{r^2}{2}$

Which gives $$2\pi \left[\frac{\ln(r)r^2}{2}\Biggr|_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 rdr\right]\implies-\frac{2\pi}{4}$$

However, the right answer should be $-\pi$ any idea where I went wrong? Also, the actual question asks me to let "$D_\delta$ be the annulus $\delta^2\le x^2+y^2\le1$ as I'm supposed to show that this integral has a finite limit which is $-\pi$ although I'm unsure on how to proceed with this and would really appreciate the communities support.

Comment: Good work but a silly mistake :) - it should have been $ \ln (x^2+y^2) = \ln (r^2) = 2 \ln r$, which would give double of your answer i.e $- \pi$

Comment: @MathLover *Hammering my head* ... simple mistakes. Any idea on how to prevent human errors like this? furthermore, do you have some support on how to correctly compute the limit which uses $\delta^2 \le x^2 +y^2 \le 1$?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434742/finding-lim-limits-x-to0x2-ln-x-without-lhospital

Comment: @MathLover Ah I think I get it now - I believe I was supposed to integrate r from $\int_{\delta}^1$ then compute the limit as $lim_{\delta \to 0}$?

Comment: On your more difficult question as to _how to prevent human errors like this_ , the problem is that we are all humans :) I wish I had a solution. My daughter loses $10$-$15$ marks every exam due to such mistakes and the only thing I keep telling her is to revise her work, be more focused into the calculation and at ease but so far it has not worked so not sure how I advise the same to others :)

Comment: Yes you are right about the limits of the integral being $\int_{\delta}^1$ and then compute $\lim_{\delta \to 0}$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for those tips! I can agree with them as they've definitely helped me throughout my learning. Though the 'at ease' part is usually the hardest! However, I do believe the greatest trait for any mathematician is luck. Without it, I wouldn't have been able to meet great people like you that helped me so much towards improving my math skills :)

Comment: The reason you must compute this as a limit is because ln(0) is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using annulus area $D_\delta=\{(x, y)|\delta^2\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$, I'll solve that integral.
Let $I_\delta$ as that value.

$$I_\delta=\int_{D_\delta}\ln(x^2+y^2)$$

Then, represent that annulus area as that... $D_\delta=\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)|\delta\leq r\leq1, 0\leq\theta\lt2\pi\}$
Then the integral $I_\delta$ goes like this.
$$I_\delta=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_\delta^12r\ln rdr=4\pi\int_\delta^1r\ln rdr$$
($\ln(x^2+y^2)=\ln r^2=2\ln r$) So...
$$I_\delta=4\pi \biggl[{\cfrac{r^2(2\ln r-1)}{4}}\biggr]_\delta^1=-\pi(2\delta^2\ln\delta-\delta^2+1)$$
Then, Gave an limit.
$$I=\lim \limits_{\delta \to 0+}{-\pi(2\delta^2\ln\delta-\delta^2+1)}=-\pi$$

That is the answer.